# Apply style setting in Activity immediately

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an Activity containing a `PreferenceFragment`. The user can change the app's style (light theme or dark theme) in this Activity. Now I want the change being visible immediately. That means, I want the style of the Activity changing when the user changes the style setting in the `PreferenceFragment`.

My idea was to listen for the preference change with `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in the `PreferenceFragment` and recreate the Activity.

But I do not think this is the right way. So, what is best practice here? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadSettings();

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
      .commit();
  }

  private void loadSettings() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
      PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    boolean darkTheme =
      sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getText(R.string.pref_theme_key).toString(), false);

    if (darkTheme) {
      setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
    }
  }
}
```

PreferenceFragment:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment
  implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
  }

  @Override
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (key.equals(getText(R.string.pref_theme_key))) {
      // recreate Activity
    }
  }
}
```

Preferences:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<CheckBoxPreference
  android:defaultValue="false"
  android:key="@string/pref_theme_key"
  android:title="@string/pref_theme" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach is correct. Listen for that preference change and then [recreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) your activity.

Editing for more context:

You should be saving this as a light/dark variant in your preferences and then when your activity is created call `setTheme` based on this **before** calling `setContentView`.

Comment: But how can a `PreferenceFragment` recreate the Activity it is part of? To make the problem clearer, I updated my question and added some code.

Comment: `getActivity().recreate()` ?

Comment: That was too easy. I was unable to see the forest for the trees. Thank you very much. By the way, it is necessary to register and unregister the listener as well.